# Multiple If/else in list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have this

```
s = ['son','abc','pro','bro']
b = ['son','bro']
c = ['pro','quo']
```

The expected output is this. Where items in the output are `index(item_in_s)` if it is present in list `b`. Or `index(item_in_s)+10` if an item is in `c`.

```
[0,12,3]
```

I tried this:

```
index_list = [s.index(item) if item in b else s.index(item)+10 if item in c for item in s]
print(index)
```

But apparently this is a syntax error. So I tried this:

```
index_list = [s.index(item) if item in b else s.index(item)+10 for item in s if item in c]
    print(index)
```

Output:

```
[12]
```

This just changes the whole logic. Although I could do this

```
fin = [s.index(item) if item in b else s.index(item)+10 if item in c  else '' for item in s]
fin = [item for item in fin if item!='']
print(fin)
```

Desired output obtained:

```
[0, 12, 3]
```

But how do I obtain what I want in list comprehension itself or is there something like `else continue` in list comprehensions?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: simply put something like `[x if x in list1 else x+10 if x in list2 for x in my_list]` which gives a syntax error.

Comment: I want something like `[x if x in list1 else x+10 if x in list2 else pass for x in my_list]` but i know pass gives syntax error too. Any alternatives?

Comment: Split your code into several lines. I don't understand what kind of output you are after in relation to the input

Comment: Just. Write. A. For. Loop. And use `enumerate` instead of `.index` which makes your algorithm inefficient.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip first i used enumerate i thought that would be inefficient. You are right it would search everytime yes.

Answer (score 13):

Fundamentally, a list-comprehension forces you to be very inefficient:

```
>>> [i if item in b else i + 10 if item in c else None for i, item in enumerate(s) if item in b or item in c]
[0, 12, 3]
```

This has to check the membership `item` in `b` and `c` *twice each* in the worst-case if you want that output. Instead, **just use a for-loop**:

```
>>> index_list = []
>>> for i, item in enumerate(s):
...     if item in b:
...         index_list.append(i)
...     elif item in c:
...         index_list.append(i + 10)
...
>>> index_list
[0, 12, 3]
>>>
```

Simple, readable, straight-forward and Pythonic.

#### Edit

You can do something close to this with [assignment expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/):

```
[
    i if item_in_b else i + 10 if item_in_c else None 
    for i, item in enumerate(s) 
    if (item_in_b:=item in b) or (item_in_c:=item in c)
]
```

but I still prefer the loop.

Comment: The condition `item in b` could be removed and only checked once when Python 3.8 comes and we can use `(item_in_b := item in b)` and do `if item_in_b` later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
index_list = [s.index(item) if item in b else s.index(item) + 10 for item in s if item in b or item in c]
```

We make sure it's in either b or c, and then the index will be either of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

your solution glitch can be solved by avoiding the elements that doesn't exist in list b&c.

you can do this by creating new list and applying simple set operation

## check this little change in your solution.

```
fin = [s.index(item) if item in b else s.index(item)+10 if item in c  else '' for item in list(set(b+c)&set(s))]
```

> by doing this your conditinal statement else is never going to execute cause list on which you are iterating only has element that either **list** in **b** or **c** only.

Answer (score 1):

already good answers given, here is one which is not mentioned yet:

```
fin = [item for item in ([s.index(item) if item in b else s.index(item)+10 if item in c  else '' for item in s]) if item!='']
print(fin)
```

basically it is a combination of the original 2 lines of code:

```
fin = [s.index(item) if item in b else s.index(item)+10 if item in c  else '' for item in s]
fin = [item for item in fin if item!='']
```

Not necessarily "faster or better", just a combination which was not given before.
When doing list comprehensions you always have the risk that you iterate more than you really need to.

A better solution would be a `for` loop, which is given in another answer.

Comment: It would be more useful if you could explain how your solution works, and how it is better than the other answers. Code-only answers are not terribly helpful.