# Python replace in list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list with different email formatting, which I want to unify all in one.
There are 2 types of email:

```
name.surname@dom
name.surname.extern@dom
```

My program allows the user to input emails, and to not have to enter `"@dom"` all the time (it's always the same one), what I've done is allowing the user to write `name.surname` or `name.surname.e` and then the script replaces those usernames with `@dom` or `.extern@dom`
The problem rises when I have all the mails in different formats stores in a list, and I want them to be filled to standards, so that if I have

```
["john.doe@dom", "john2.doe", "john3.doe.e","john4.doe.extern@dom"]
```

it all ends up looking like this

```
["john.doe@dom", "john2.doe@dom", "john3.doe.extern@dom","john4.doe.extern@dom"]
```

I have tried with list comprehensions, but all I got was three concatenations:

```
["%s.xtern@dom" % x for x in mails if x[-2:] == ".e"] +
["%s@dom" %x for x in mails if "@dom not in mails" and x[-2:] != ".e"] + 
[x for x in mails if "@dom" in x]
```

I'm sure there's a better way that does not require me to do 3 list comprehensions and that does not require me to do

```
for i,v in enumerate(mails):
    if "@dom" not in v:
        mails[i] = "%s@dom" % v
    etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string's `endswith()` method to determine what you need to do with the input:

```
mails = ["john.doe@dom", "john2.doe", "john3.doe.e","john4.doe.extern@dom"]

final_mails = []

for mail in mails:
    if mail.endswith("@dom"):
        # Use as-is if it ends with @dom.
        final_mails.append(mail)
    elif mail.endswith(".e"):
        # Replace to extern@dom if it ends with .e
        final_mails.append(mail.replace(".e", ".extern@dom"))
    else:
        # Add @dom on all other cases
        final_mails.append("{}@dom".format(mail))

print final_mails

# Result: ['john.doe@dom', 'john2.doe@dom', 'john3.doe.extern@dom', 'john4.doe.extern@dom']
```

It might need more thorough checks to not accept things like `@dom` right in the middle of the name and whatnot. Hope that helps you out though!

Edit:
Just for fun, if you insist on a list comprehension:

```
mails = ["john.doe@dom", "john2.doe", "john3.doe.e","john4.doe.extern@dom"]

final_mails = ["{}@dom".format((mail.replace(".e", ".extern@dom") 
               if mail.endswith(".e") else mail).rstrip("@dom")) 
               for mail in mails]

print final_mails

# Result: ['john.doe@dom', 'john2.doe@dom', 'john3.doe.extern@dom', 'john4.doe.extern@dom']
```

Personally I find list comprehensions are best when they are short and readable, so I would stick with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Option without listcomprehensions:

```
maillist = ["john.doe@dom", "john2.doe",    "john3.doe.e","john4.doe.extern@dom"]

for i in range(len(maillist)): 
    if "@" not in maillist[i]:
        if maillist[i][-2:]== ".e": 
            maillist[i] += ("xtern@dom") 
        else: 
            maillist[i] +=  "@dom"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a one-liner, combine [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) with [multiple if/else statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513457/multiple-if-else-in-list-comprehension-python):

```
first_list = ["john.doe@dom", "john2.doe", "john3.doe.e","john4.doe.extern@dom"]

second_list = [email + 'xtern@dom' if email.endswith(".e") else \
               email if email.endswith("@dom") else "{}@dom".format(email) \
                   for email in first_list]

print second_list
```

Gives:

```
['john.doe@dom', 'john2.doe@dom', 'john3.doe.extern@dom', 'john4.doe.extern@dom']
```

Answer (score 0):

@Green Cell was faster than me and his answer seems to be correct. Here is a list comprehension that does the same thing :

```
mails = ["john.doe@dom", "john2.doe", "john3.doe.e","john4.doe.extern@dom"]

print mails

mails = [mail if mail.endswith("@dom") else mail.replace(".e", ".extern@dom") if mail.endswith(".e") else "{}@dom".format(mail) for mail in mails]

print mails
```

Which outputs :

```
['john.doe@dom', 'john2.doe', 'john3.doe.e', 'john4.doe.extern@dom']
['john.doe@dom', 'john2.doe@dom', 'john3.doe.extern@dom', 'john4.doe.extern@dom']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I came with a different solution in the end: Declaring a help function.

```
def mailfy(mail):
   if mail.endswith(".c"):
     return mail[:-2] + "@dom"
   ...

mails = [mailfy(x) for x in mails]
```